# looking for the best string gauge to play drop tunings from drop c to drop A

Tags: string-gauge

I have found some 12-60's in DR brand and was curious what the highest tuning they could reach and the lowest tuning they could reach with no issues my current plan as far as playing setup is to have a 6 string for E standard to drop c at lowest (Ernie ball cobalt 10-52 STHB) a 6 string for drop c to drop A if possible (without having to change strings) and a 7 string for even lower tunings when I want to play bands like Rivers Of Nihle Korn ETC if anyone could point me in the best direction to do all that I have listed without having to change out strings for certain tunings it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Maybe a good idea to say what guitar? And what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

> if anyone could point me in the best direction

I think *direction* is the best we can offer.

The first thing to consider is how string tension changes when you change tuning. You will find many string gauge/tension calculators in the internet. Note, tension depends also on the guitar scale. You need to answer what kind of tension you can tolerate. But this also may change as you get used to over time.

The second thing is sound quality. The thicker the strings, the less overtones they produce, and the more likely are issues with inharmonicity. These are the main reasons people choose longer scale guitars for low tunings. In rock and metal you can get away with quite a lot, and you're the only one to answer what is tolerable.

A potential issue I see with your plan that if you move the whole tuning by 2-3 semitones, you may need to adjust neck and bridge setup each time, or accept an additional compromise in this aspect.

But give it a try, check string gauges, buy several string sets and see if they fit you.

Comment: Intonantion is likely to be problematic with the lower strings, as there may not be enough room to move saddles backwards.

Comment: @Tim good point! One more reason to use longer scale for low tuning!